# Google Account Id

Tags: google-cloud-platform, account, user-accounts

I need to get user's account id , and not user's id.

I need a unique identifier for all organization users and for that purpose I'm looking for an api request to get the user's account id .

However I can't find a way to do so.

Any idea?
Thanks!

I tried to look in google docs and especially in [https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/*}/connections](https://people.googleapis.com/v1/%7BresourceName=people/*%7D/connections)
But all it returns is a resource name with the user id which is not unique it differs from user to user.

Comment: Any luck, have you found it?